# What is regression layer in a spatial transformer?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, deepmind, transformer

I came across this line while reading the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02025) on Spatial Transformers by Deepmind in the last paragraph of Sec 3.1:

> The localisation network function floc() can take any form, such as a fully-connected network or a convolutional network, but should include a final regression layer to produce the transformation parameters θ.

I understand what regression is, but what is meant by a regression layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it means that the "localization network" should output a set of real valued parameters (typically 6 numbers). The word "regression" doesn't bear any specific meaning.

Any network that relies on the original image as input (directly or indirectly) and outputs 6 numbers, would work. And its last layer would qualify as "regression layer" as long as it is not restricted in the real domain (not normalized, softmaxed, etc)